# Trying to use Laravel policies into components

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to use Policies inside a Post Component, using Laravel. This is how I'm iterating through the posts in my page.

```
       @foreach($posts as $post)
            <x-post 
               :id="$post->id" 
               :title="$post->title" 
               :description="$post->description" 
               :userId="$post->user_id" 
               :img="$post->img" 
               :author="$post->user->name"/>
        @endforeach
```

In the post.blade.php I'm trying to use a 'update' policy method to define which users can see the post:

```
@can('update', Auth::user(), /*What shoud I pass here?*/)
      <a class="btn btn-success"href="{{route('posts.edit', $id)}}">
           <i class="bi bi-pencil"></i>
      </a>
@endcan
```

What should I pass as the second parameter of the policy? Normally, it would be a post variable. Since I'm already inside a post, I don't know to proceed.

Comment: This is not how to do it. The policy is supposed to be checked at the controller level. But if you're just using properties of the post model, why not pass it to the component instead of having all the attributes set in the view? That way you could use `$post` as you desire. E.g. `<x-post :post="$post"/>` and done.

Comment: @miken32 is it a good practice to pass the entire variable to the view? Because I'm only using a few of the attributes of the post. It's my first time using components btw.

Comment: There's no reason not to do it. Saves defining all those attributes in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check outside the component. Something like

```xml
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    <x-post 
        :id="$post->id" 
        :title="$post->title" 
        :description="$post->description" 
        :userId="$post->user_id" 
        :img="$post->img" 
        :author="$post->user->name"
        :canUpdate="Auth::user()->can('update', $post)"/>
@endforeach
```

```xml
@if ($canUpdate)
    <a class="btn btn-success"href="{{ route('posts.edit', $id) }}">
        <i class="bi bi-pencil"></i>
    </a>
@endif
```

Comment: This works just fine. Thank you very much!